# Why is this OpenGL framebuffer color attachment incomplete?

Tags: c, opengl, framebuffer

I've been following [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/) tutorial on rendering to an off-screen texture, but I'm having difficulty creating the render target.
I've registered an error callback function and I'm getting a `GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER` error back with a `GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API` source, which is getting spat out by `glCheckNamedFramebufferStatus()` with the message:

> FBO incomplete: color attachment incomplete[0].

I'm struggling to see what I'm missing here, I've double checked the parameters that I'm passing into the OpenGL functions and tried removing the `glTexParameteri` calls but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```c
GLuint framebuffer = 0;
GLuint renderedTexture;
GLenum drawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS0};

bool buildOffscreenBuffer()
{
    // creating frame & render texture to draw picker buffer to
    glGenFramebuffers(1,  &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
                                                                                              
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1920, 1080,
            0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
                                                                                              
    // configuring framebuffer
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
            renderedTexture, 0);
    glDrawBuffers(1, drawBuffers);
                                                                                              
    return glCheckNamedFramebufferStatus(framebuffer, GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE;
}
```

**Update:**
As per [derhass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65030135/11058021), it seems that GL_RGB isn't required as per the spec. I've tried updating this to GL_RGBA but I'm getting the same error. Since this may be implementation related, I'll list my card and driver:

Card: RX Vega 56

Driver: [mesa/amdgpu](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU)

Comment: Please provide an example which actually produces the issue. Btw, you might check [my dirty FBO example](https://github.com/derhass/miscstuff/blob/master/OpenGL/code/HelloFBO.c) (compile via `gcc HelloFBO.c -lglfw -lGLEW -lGL`), I'd be surprised if that wouldn't run on mesa/amdgpu. Just add the framebuffer completness checks, and change the FBO dimensions if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get to the bottom of this. I'd actually fixed the bug in simplifying the example for the post.

```c
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1920, 1080,
            0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

Was actually getting the width and height from a helper function that from a platform layer, however that function returned a `struct {int, int}` that I was storing in a `struct {float, float}` . This resulted in garbage being passed as the width and height to `glTexImage2D`.

Answer (score 3):

As per the GL spec, `GL_RGB` is not in the set of *required renderable formats*, so implementations are free to not support it. Try `GL_RGBA` instead.

Comment: Same error with GL_RGBA I'm afraid. I didn't realise that GL_RGB wasn't required by the spec. I'll update the question with some driver information

Comment: You still haven't updated the source code for the texture format.

Comment: My bad, looked at this first thing in the morning and I missed that in the update